# Storing in-memory data in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, graph, mapreduce, distributed-computing, in-memory

We are working on Hadoop Map-Reduce for computation of distributed graph. The graph is represented as adjacency list and stored in files. These files are stored on HDFS.

The task is to read these files and create an in-memory graph by different nodes of the cluster so that any number of queries can be executed upon that "in-memory graph". Examples for a query can be searching the neighbors, traversals etc.

We are facing a problem at creating and storing these in-memory graph in the nodes. Can anyone please help us achieve this?

Edit: To be more clear on the requirement, the in-memory graph needs to be constructed to reduce the latency caused due to I/O operations done during map-reduce. The files should be read only once in memory and kept intact so that further computations can be done on that rather than reading it from the secondary storage.

Comment: Maybe you should be a little more specific, what is specifically your problem doing this? Are you using Giraph? Which input and output formats are using? What error code are you getting?

Comment: @chomp We are not using Giraph. Our input is the graph which is stored in files on HDFS which have the adjacency lists. We are not getting the error code, but trying to find a way to represent the graph in-memory on nodes so that further processing on the graph would be faster as it requires less I/O if it is in memory [which is the requirement of the project].

Comment: Accessing the HDFS files are not very different than accessing normal one. so, process the files and create in memory graph in the same manner as if file is in local. I do not think this is a problem with hadoop. Basically you are looking logic to create a in-memory graph- right?

Comment: @gyan Yes, our requirement is to have the graph in-memory. The first time the graph is read from files and stored in memory. My requirement is that once read, the graph in memory should persist for further computations or queries that can be performed on the graph without doing I/O operations.